# How to receive data from the printer(HP LaserJet Pro M305d); for example Load Paper, In windows form Application .Net 4.5 C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, .net-4.5

as i said i am developing windows form application using .Net 4.5 C#, Now i want to receive info about the printer status, i used one of the way i found, here is it:

```
 private bool IsPrinterPaperAvailable()
    {
        // Get the default printer
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        string defaultPrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

        // Create a PrintServer object to manage the printer queue
        using (PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer())
        {
            // Get the printer queue for the default printer
            PrintQueue printQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), defaultPrinterName);
            
            printQueue.Refresh();

            // Check if the printer queue has paper
            if (printQueue.IsOutOfPaper)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

this expression: printQueue.IsOutOfPaper is always returning false and all of the other option that printQueue Offers, i think the problem is not from my code, i think the problem is i am not sending or letting the printer send the printer status, is there a specific drive i have to install. ps: even in when i open the printer from windows it is giving me this status: 0 document in queues, i hope you guys can help me out, i am trying to solve this issue for like a week.

Comment: What printer do you use for testing? Most printers don't support this property. Only the really expensive ones. Also the property will usually not be populated if there is no open print job in the printer queue.

Comment: i am using HP LaserJet Pro M305d, i want to check first if there is a paper in the printer then i will send the print job, i hope u understand me.

Comment: This doesn't work as you expect. Most printers will (if at all) only set the PaperOut property if there is actually an open print job for that printer.

Comment: ok, is there another way to do it ?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no general way of querying a printer whether it has paper.

Comment: what about the printer status, the printer status as i can see in the HP smart it is giving me All Trays Are Empty, how can i get this printer status.